Why would a sinner both love and hate houses (Gabriela Mistral)?
In Gabriela Mistral's poem Flores, part of the posthumously published Poema de Chile, we find the following stanzas (emphasis added):

— No te entiendo ¿por qué tú
siempre andas pensando
para mí en una parada,
en hoyos de aburrimiento
de una casa y otra casa...?
— Es que, como el pecador,
amo y destesto las casas:
me las quiero de rendida,
las detesto de quedada.

Translation (automatic translation with some corrections):

— I don't understand why you
always go around thinking
for me at a standstill,
in holes of boredom
at one house after another...?
— It is that, like the sinner,
I love and loathe houses:
I love them when I'm tired,
I loathe them when I stay.

I don't understand why sinners would both love and hate houses, i.e. how this would be related to being a sinner. Moreover, Gabriela Mistral was a Catholic and the Catholic church considers all people sinners, but not all Catholics both love and hate houses.

Sidenote: in Ursula K. Le Guin's bilingual edition, the lines quoted above are in a poem titled "Casas" ("Houses", pages 351–353), which does not completely match the online text of "Flores".

To set the poem in context, it is part of the Poema de Chile, Mistral's last anthology of poetry first published in 1967, after her death. The anthology is organized as a journey of three beings - Gabriela/Lucila (a soul or angel, or perhaps a ghost), a little Indian boy, and a young deer - who cross the country from north to south, talking about what they encounter.
In this poem, the ghost tells the boy about her dislike of houses, and contrasts it to her love of nature, especially the mountains: "The hills tell stories, the houses little or nothing... houses suffocate me. Listen, when they make them, they waste the mountains, they barely look at them". This strongly reflects Mistral's own love of nature, and how she found the natural world to be a strong source of inspiration.
However in the verse quoted by the OP, towards the end of the poem, the ghost admits that even she appreciates houses sometimes. The meaning of the lines is rather obscured by the automatic translation, so I will render them in my own words:

I'm like a sinner,  I love and I hate houses:  I love them when I surrender to them,  I hate them when I leave.

The ghost (Mistral) feels hypocrisy within herself, and compares herself to a sinner. A sinner relishes the sin while in commission of it (gluttony, pride, lust etc), but regrets it subsequently. In the same way the ghost enjoys the shelter of a house when she needs protection from the elements, and "surrenders" to the comfort they provide, but reverts to her dislike of houses once she leaves.
